# How to implement this data in angular-chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, angular-chart

I am trying chart using `angular-chart.js`. While going through this documentation: [Link For angular-chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) 
pie chart, I have found out that, they have given `$scope.data` for values and `$scope.labels` for labels. But I have data like this.

```js
$scope.pied = [{
       "Prospective":"4",
        "CallBacks"
:"0",
        "FollowUp"
: "4",
        "NotInterested"
:"1",
         "Closed"
: "0"
        }];
```

How to implement this data in angular-chart?

Comment: What have you tried so far? it seems you need to modify to data to make it work.

Comment: i am getting these values from service i can't change the json shaohao Lin bro

Comment: It's ok that you get it from service. You don't need to change the json, but you can modify the response json to some data structure to fit the requirement of the angualr-chart.js

Comment: Service response is updated how can I implement this

Comment: Can you make a plunker and update your code?

Comment: Yeah okay tomorrow will update that lin bro

Answer (score 2):

You can use [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) to loop through the received data and generate the required structure e.g.

```
$scope.data = [];
$scope.labels = [];
angular.forEach($scope.pied, function (object) {
    for (var key in object) {
        $scope.data.push(object[key]);
        $scope.labels.push(key);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks jtblin I will try this and revert back

Comment: hi jtblin i have to use this forEach in this code?                       $scope.pied = [{
       "Prospective":"4",
        "CallBacks":"0",                                                                              "FollowUp": "4",                                                                 "NotInterested":"1",
 "Closed": "0"
        }];    i need to put 4,0,4,1,0 in data and names in labels

Comment: Thanks for the forEach jtblin  :)